# Extract controls from HTML video

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I was wondering if it is possible to extract the controls of a video. I mean that instead of being the controls on top of the video, that these were separate and that the video could be controlled from there. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That would be awesome: having native controls separated from video so that we don"t have to build custom controls. But still be able to add stuff to these native controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can try this...............

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function vidplay() {
           var video = document.getElementById("Video1");
           var button = document.getElementById("play");
           if (video.paused) {
              video.play();
              button.textContent = "||";
           } else {
              video.pause();
              button.textContent = ">";
           }
        }

        function restart() {
            var video = document.getElementById("Video1");
            video.currentTime = 0;
        }

        function skip(value) {
            var video = document.getElementById("Video1");
            video.currentTime += value;
        }      
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>        

    <video id="Video1" autoplay>
    //  Replace these with your own video files. 
         <source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />

         <a href="1.mp4">Download the video</a> file.
    </video>

    <div id="buttonbar">
        <button id="restart" onclick="restart();">[]</button> 
        <button id="rew" onclick="skip(-10)">&lt;&lt;</button>
        <button id="play" onclick="vidplay()">&gt;</button>
        <button id="fastFwd" onclick="skip(10)">&gt;&gt;</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you can disable your browser's controls by *not* setting the attribute `controls`. see https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_video_controls.asp

Then you can define your own custom controls by adding event handlers to the UI elements you wish to use for controlling playback.

```
function playBtnHandler(event) {
  myVideo.play();
}

myBtn.addEventListener("click", playBtnHandler);
```

Comment: Yes basically, if you want custom controls, use custom controls.